# HOW TO READ LINE FROM A TEXT FILE INTO AN 2D ARRAY IN PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, file

So, the text file looks like this:
[[7, 5, 3], [3, 2, 2], [9, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2], [4, 3, 3]]

The question is how can I read the line and make it a 2d array that has 5 rows and 3 columns? I have tried this code but this error came out "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (5,3)"

```
file = open("test.txt", "r")
allocation = np.array(file.readline())
all = np.reshape(allocation, (5,3))
print(allocation)

file.close()
```

Sorry if the question has already been asked before but I don't really understand other solutions. Thank you.

Comment: what other solutions don't you understand?

Comment: Take a look at the `np.loadtxt` function

Comment: Either intentionally or coincidentally, but that file is a JSON, and you could load it with `json.load()`.

Comment: Since no one but use has a that file, your example should hardcode the value returned by `file.readline()`

Answer (score 2):

One straightforward approach uses the `eval()` function:

```py
inp = "[[7, 5, 3], [3, 2, 2], [9, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2], [4, 3, 3]]"
arr = eval(inp)
print(arr)  # [[7, 5, 3], [3, 2, 2], [9, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2], [4, 3, 3]]
print(arr[1][1])  # 2
```